# Join to same table match date ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date, join

Ships arrive daily at a port with "P" passengers. Each ship has a name "N" and arrives at most once per day.
I have a table of this data thus:

```
Date          N          P

2013-11-27    A         12
2013-11-27    G         16
2013-11-27    B         56
2013-11-28    A         10
2013-11-29    B         19
2013-11-29    A         19
2013-11-30    G         18
2013-11-30    B         13
2013-11-30    A         11
```

I want to compare one ship's 'A' passenger count to another 'B' for a given time span but only when they arrive ON THE SAME DAY.  So the result is

```
Date          PA        PB

2013-11-27    12        56
2013-11-29    19        19
2013-11-30    11        13
```

Note no 'B' on the 28th so neither reported (and vice versa).

Some kind of outer join on the same table?

```
SELECT A.Date, A.P as PA, B.P AS PB 
FROM Arrivals A OUTER JOIN Arrivals B ON A.Date = B.Date
WHERE ... ???

Date >= @start AND Date <= @end AND
A.N = 'A' AND B.N = 'B'
```

The above query is the start I have in mind but I don't know how to complete it. Anyone know the query?
SQL Server 2008
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please clean up your question here, not really sure what you are asking? Are you asking for the query that will give the result that you listed in the table?

Comment: What error are you seeing? Does `@start` and `@end` has a valid date value? What do you expect instead of `... ???`?

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
SELECT A.Date, A.P as PA, B.P AS PB 
FROM (Select * FROM Arrivals WHERE N = 'A') A 
INNER JOIN (Select * FROM Arrivals WHERE N = 'B') B 
ON A.Date = B.Date
```

Comment: I have no idea what you answered.

Comment: Yes it does. I need to think of subqueries more. Thanks Jorg.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
create table #tmp 
(
dt date, 
n varchar (1) , 
p int
)
GO

insert into #tmp
values 
('2013-11-27'   , 'A'      ,   12),
('2013-11-27' ,   'G'  ,       16),
('2013-11-27'   , 'B'       ,  56),
('2013-11-28' ,   'A' ,        10),
('2013-11-29'   , 'B'  ,       19),
('2013-11-29'   , 'A' ,        19),
('2013-11-30'   , 'G' ,        18),
('2013-11-30'   , 'B' ,        13),
('2013-11-30'   , 'A' ,        11)

GO

select distinct 
a.dt,
(select SUM(p) from #tmp y where y.dt = a.dt and y.n = 'A') pa,
(select SUM(p) from #tmp y where y.dt = a.dt and y.n = 'B') pb,
(select SUM(p) from #tmp y where y.dt = a.dt and y.n = 'G') pG
from #tmp a
group by a.dt, a.n

Go 
drop table #tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH ARRIVAL_A AS
(SELECT DATE, P FROM ARRIVALS WHERE N = 'A'),
ARRIVAL_B AS
(SELECT DATE, P FROM ARRIVALS WHERE N = 'B')
SELECT ARRIVAL_A.DATE, ARRIVAL_A.P [PA], ARRIVAL_B.P [PB]
FROM ARRIVAL_A INNER JOIN ARRIVAL_B
ON ARRIVAL_A.DATE = ARRIVAL_B.DATE
```